# Connecting Multiple PannerNodes to output

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to connect multiple PannerNodes to an output but I have a problem with proper connecting them (while testing I have no audio). Audio is multichannel so I want to process each channel separately and audio is form html video element.

My main problem is that I have 6 different PannerNodes each one have one output with 2 channels and I don't know how to properly connect them to the destination to have a stereo output (or any output but my system is supporting only stereo).

Here is what I am doing:

1. Creating audioContext, MediaElementSource, etc. and first connection.

```
    const context = new AudioContext();
    
    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(video);
    
    var dest = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
    
    //Spliter channels L, R, SL, SR, C, LFE
    let splitter = new ChannelSplitterNode(context, {numberOfOutputs: 6});

    // I didn't used that later because I don't know if that is necessary and how to implement it properly (with that line commented it code is still not working correctly)
    let channel_merger = new ChannelMergerNode(context, {numberOfInputs: 2});
    
    let listener = context.listener;
    
    source.connect(splitter, 0, 0);
```

2. Setup the listener

```
    if(listener.forwardX) {
        listener.forwardX.setValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime);
        listener.forwardY.setValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime);
        listener.forwardZ.setValueAtTime(-1, audioCtx.currentTime);
        listener.upX.setValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime);
        listener.upY.setValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime);
        listener.upZ.setValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime);
      } else {
        listener.setOrientation(0,0,-1,0,1,0);
      }
```

3. Creates PannerNodes and connects it to a splitter

```
    var FrontLeft, FrontCenter, FrontRight, SurroundLeft, SurroundRight, Sub = null;
    
    var pannerNodesObjects = [FrontLeft, FrontCenter, FrontRight, SurroundLeft, SurroundRight, Sub];
    
    function set_pannerNode(node, panningModel /* 'HRTF' */, distanceModel /* Possible values are "linear", "inverse" and "exponential". The default value is "inverse". */, refDistance, maxDistance, rolloffFactor, coneInnerAngle, coneOuterAngle, coneOuterGain, x, y, z /* position */, n /* index of the pannerNodesObjects */) {
      
      node = context.createPanner();
    
      // Seting options
      node.panningModel = panningModel;
      node.distanceModel = distanceModel;
      node.refDistance = refDistance;
      node.maxDistance = maxDistance;
      node.rolloffFactor = rolloffFactor;
      node.coneInnerAngle = coneInnerAngle;
      node.coneOuterAngle = coneOuterAngle;
      node.coneOuterGain = coneOuterGain;
    
      // Setting position
      node.positionX = x;
      node.positionY = y;
      node.positionZ = z;
      pannerNodesObjects[n] = node;
    }
    
    for (i=0; i< pannerNodesObjects.length; i++){
        [nx, ny, nz] = set_rotation(distanceFromScreen,screenCenterY,angleList[i],i); // Here I get a position of the PannerNode
        set_pannerNode(pannerNodesObjects[i],'HRTF',"exponential", 1,100,2,360,0,0, nx, ny, nz, i);
        splitter.connect(pannerNodesObjects[i], i);
      }
```

4. Connect PannerNodes to destination

```
    for (i=0; i< pannerNodesObjects.length; i++){
        pannerNodesObjects[i].connect(dest);
    }
```

After that I am updating each PannerNode position in a loop. But I have no audio while playing the video so I probably done something wrong with AudioNodes connection.

Comment: Can you get an example with a single panner working?

Comment: It would also be awesome if you put it all into a jsfiddle or codepen or whatever.